# How to move IntelliJ file tabs?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, when you open a bunch of source files, is there a way to rearrange the order of the file tabs?  In Eclipse you can drag and drop but I don't see a way to do this in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a free TabReorder plugin to do this, available at http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=187